# Writing a bash script to sftp with ssh-keys that have a password - SSH_ASKPASS is not working

Tags: openssh, ssh-agent

I am writing a script in bash to `sftp` files to another server. I have an SSH key with a password as its required. I have tried using `SSH_ASKPASS` variable but its not working.

```
DISPLAY=: SSH_ASKPASS=/root/.ssh/ask.sh setsid ssh-add ~/.ssh/bl_test
Enter passphrase for /root/.ssh/bl_test:
```

that's not working. I have also tried

```
 echo foo | SSH_ASKPASS=/root/.ssh/ask.sh DISPLAY= ssh-add ~/.ssh/bl_test
```

That just creates a loop running my `ask.sh`.

I have set `DISPLAY=:` I start ssh_agent eval `ssh-agent -s` I have set `SSH_ASKPASS=~/.ssh/ask.sh` in my script and nothing is working. Do I need to load software to get SSH_ASKPASS to work on AWS2 linux?

**Please help.**

Shane

Comment: Is `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" defined in the environment of the `sftp` process (and is it the same value as for `ssh-add`)? Can you run `ssh-add -l` immediately before `sftp`? What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

you may to use a combination of ssh-agent and expect command because ssh-agent cannot store the passphrase

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Variables
set PRIVATE_KEY_PATH "key.key"
set PASSPHRASE "passpass"

# start ssh-agent
eval spawn ssh-agent

# add your private key to ssh-agent
spawn ssh-add $PRIVATE_KEY_PATH

# wait input of  passphrase
expect "Enter passphrase for $PRIVATE_KEY_PATH:"

# send the passphrase
send "$PASSPHRASE\r"

# wait end of ssh-add
expect eof
```